# Storing a JWT token in Blazor Client Side

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor

I am trying my first Blazor app, client side, and am battling with authentication. I have managed to call my API, get a token, and authenticate in the app. I need to store the JWT token somewhere - and I thought, in the claims, might be OK. (Maybe this is where I go wrong, and it should be somehow, in LocalStorage or something?)

So for my authorisation, I have a `AuthenticationStateProvider`, where - things work OK. I get authenticated. But I am unable to acceess my token.

Is this the right place to be adding it? And if so, why is this code failing me?

```
    public class CustomAuthenticationStaterProvider : AuthenticationStateProvider
    {
        public override Task<AuthenticationState> GetAuthenticationStateAsync()
        {
            var identity = new ClaimsIdentity();

            var user = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);

            return Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(user));
        }

        public void AuthenticateUser(AuthenticationResponse request)
        {
            if (request.ResponseDetails.IsSuccess == false)
                return;

            var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(new[]
            {
                new Claim("token", request.Token),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, request.Email),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, $"{request.Firstname} {request.Surname}"),
            }, "apiauth_type");

            var user = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);

            NotifyAuthenticationStateChanged(Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(user)));
        }

        public void LogoutUser()
        {
            // Hwo??
         
        }
    }
```

My index page is working:

```
    <Authorized>
        <p>Welcome, @context.User.Identity.Name</p>
    </Authorized>
    <NotAuthorized>
        <p>You're not signed in</p>
    </NotAuthorized>
</AuthorizeView>
```

It shows my name, when logged in, as expected.

But on a page where I need to send the JWT token to the API, I am trying to find it:

```
        var user = authState.User;
```

But `user` seems to have no 'token' parameter.

[image]

How should I be storing my JWT, and having access to it when ever I am about to use my http client?

Comment: Why aren't you using Identity Cookie authentication? Storing an access token in the localStorage or sessionStorage (js) makes the token accessible for every javascript file you include on your webpage

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You save token in local storage of web browser. something like this

```cs
using Microsoft.JSInterop;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace BlazorApp.Services
{
    public interface ILocalStorageService
    {
        Task<T> GetItem<T>(string key);
        Task SetItem<T>(string key, T value);
        Task RemoveItem(string key);
    }

    public class LocalStorageService : ILocalStorageService
    {
        private IJSRuntime _jsRuntime;

        public LocalStorageService(IJSRuntime jsRuntime)
        {
            _jsRuntime = jsRuntime;
        }

        public async Task<T> GetItem<T>(string key)
        {
            var json = await _jsRuntime.InvokeAsync<string>("localStorage.getItem", key);

            if (json == null)
                return default;

            return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(json);
        }

        public async Task SetItem<T>(string key, T value)
        {
            await _jsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("localStorage.setItem", key, JsonSerializer.Serialize(value));
        }

        public async Task RemoveItem(string key)
        {
            await _jsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("localStorage.removeItem", key);
        }
    }
}
```

source: https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2020/08/13/blazor-webassembly-jwt-authentication-example-tutorial

Comment: Tokens should be store in session IMO

Comment: @aguafrommars isn't the session going to be re-initialized every time we close and reopen the browser ? It seems like it would destroy the user experience to have to reconnect every time

Comment: @pascx64 if the session cookie is still valid the user will not have to reconnect after closing the browser, SSO should still work. OAuth tokens are store in the session store by the default Blazor OAuth handler

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you use Blazored library. They provide both local and session storage options. I use the latter. Information on https://github.com/Blazored/SessionStorage

Answer (score 1):

The following answer is relevant if you are relying on Msal for authentication, such as using it with Azure B2C:

```
builder.Services.AddMsalAuthentication(options =>
{
    ...
    options.ProviderOptions.Cache.CacheLocation = "localStorage";
});
```